# Setting Toolbar using setSupportActionBar() when resuming a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

In my app I have:

- ActionBarActivity A
- Fragment1 with Toolbar1
- Fragment2 with Toolbar2

ActionBarActivity A shows Fragment 1 (which uses the Activity's setSupportActionBar() method to set toolbar1 as the actionbar).

Pressing on a button, shows Fragment 2 (using the FragmentTransation's add() method), and now Fragment2 sets toolbar2 as the actionbar using setSupportActionBar().

Pressing on back pops the backstack to show Fragment1 again. Here I want toolbar1 to be set as the actionbar again.

What is the easiest way to achieve this? (hopefully without trying to understand which Fragment is shown and setting the toolbar from each fragment)

Answer (score 0):

Use [onBackStackChangedListener.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener.html)

```
        getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
        @Override public void onBackStackChanged() {
            //get the fragment.
            if (fragment instanceof BaseFragment) {
                //set action bar
                setActionBar(((BaseFragment)fragment).getActionBar());
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: What is "get the fragment"? I want something generic, to apply on all my fragments (not look for each one by tag)

Comment: You need to get a reference to the fragment currently being displayed. Use findFragmentById.

Comment: How can you make it generic if each fragment sets a different ActionBar?

Comment: And what id am I looking for? As I said, I don't want to be checking the, one by one

Comment: By having the fragments implement an interface that provides the toolbar to the activity

Comment: How are you placing the fragment in the layout? You assign an id to the fragment when you added it. Use that.

Comment: If you have a custom Fragment class, you can implement a method like getActionBar(). See updated code.